# XML transformation based on attributes endings

Tags: xml, xslt

I've this xml code:

```
<items>
    <item name="xyz_low" />
    <item name="xyz_hight" />
    <item name="xyz_medium" />
    <item name="abc_medium" />
    <item name="abc_low" />
    <item name="abc_hight" />
</items>
```

I would like to get something like:

```
<items>
    <item name="xyz_hight" />
    <item name="xyz_medium" />
    <item name="xyz_low" />
    <item name="abc_hight" />
    <item name="abc_medium" />
    <item name="abc_low" />
</items>
```

The sorting happens only between tags with the same first part of the attribute name (the part before the underscore). The order is hight, medium and low.

I've look at `ends-with`, but it's not enough for me because I don't know if the first part could be xyz, abc or something else.

I don't need to sort the first part: I just want to sort the suffixes within the group of item tags starting in the same way.

Is it possible or I should choose a different approach?

Comment: @IanRoberts XSLT 2.0 is ok, but it would be better with XSLT 1.0/1.1, but I suppose that it could be very complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort items in a certain fixed order like this you can use a trick like this: define a variable for the sort order

```
<xsl:variable name="sortOrder" select="'|hight|medium|low|'" />
```

and now you can sort using

```
<xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder, concat('|', value, '|')))"
          data-type="number" />
```

for whatever `value` you need.  If the `value` is "hight" then the `substring-before` will be of length 0, for "medium" it'll be of length 6, etc.

Here's an XSLT 2.0 template that'll do what you're after, assuming that variable definition

```
<xsl:template match="items">
  <items>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-adjacent="substring-before(@name, '_')">
      <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder,
                                concat('|', substring-after(@name, '_'), '|')))"
          data-type="number" />
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </items>
</xsl:template>
```

To do the same in XSLT 1.0 you'd need to do a Muenchian grouping trick

```
<xsl:key name="itemByPrefix" match="item" use="substring-before(@name, '_')" />
```

and then in the template

```
<xsl:template match="items">
  <items>
    <xsl:for-each select="item[generate-id() = generate-id(
                key('itemByPrefix', substring-before(@name, '_'))[1])]">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('itemByPrefix', substring-before(@name, '_'))">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder,
                                concat('|', substring-after(@name, '_'), '|')))"
          data-type="number" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </items>
</xsl:template>
```

(the XSLT 2.0 version still works if there are several different sets of `items` in the source document, the XSLT 1.0 version would get a lot messier in that case).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know I could use it when name has multiple underscores? Like "a_b_c_low"

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli in XSLT 2.0 there are various options, you could use regex functions e.g. `replace(@name, '^.*?_([^_]*$)', '$1')` instead of `substring-after(@name, '_')`, but in XSLT 1.0 string manipulation is much more limited (unless you can use processor-specific extension functions).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I'll try to adapt the template in order to recreate the original input file structure and it will be perfect.

Comment: `group-by` it's better if they are not adjacent