# XSLT 2.0 - Two steps sorting

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

my XML tag contains many items that should be threated as three different groups, with similar (but different) sorting rules.

This is what I want to get:

```
<items>
    <!-- Header - for-each sorting -->
    <item name="something1_A"/>
    <item name="something2_B"/>
    <item name="something3_C"/>

    <!-- Body - for-each-group sorting -->
    <item name="something4_D"/>
    <item name="something4_E"/>
    <item name="something5_D"/>
    <item name="something5_E"/>

    <!-- Footer - for-each sorting -->
    <item name="something6_F"/>
    <item name="something6_G"/>
    <item name="something6_H"/>
</items>
```

Initially, items order is random.

**The first sort should create those three different parts**: put everything that is header on the top, everything that is footer on the bottom, and keep everything else where it is. I can determine if something should go in the header, in the body or in the footer looking at its ending (the value after the last underscore).

**The second sort should work differently on each of those parts** (per-element sorting for header and footer, per-group sorting for body).

I know how I can sort the header, the body and the footer (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794279/1312346)), but not how to move them and sort them with different algorithms.

Comment: You mean custom sorting?

Comment: @NavinRawat I don't know how to call it properly. Maybe if I could write a better `select` I would have three xsl:sort only, one for part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `template` that matches `items` then it's just a case of separating the `item` elements into three groups, which you say you can do via the endings:

```
<xsl:variable name="headerItems" select="item[
   some $suf in ('_A', '_B', '_C') satisfies ends-with(@name, $suf)]" />
<xsl:variable name="footerItems" select="item[
   some $suf in ('_F', '_G', '_H') satisfies ends-with(@name, $suf)]" />
<xsl:variable name="bodyItems"
   select="item except ($headerItems | $footerItems)" />
```

and then handling the three groups in sequence however you need to.